# Given $f'(2)$ does not exist and $f"(2)>0$, is $x = 2$ a max, min, or neither?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Initially I thought that f''(x) would be undefined if f'(x) is also undefined. Nonetheless, I am not sure if this premise applies to every possible function. My approach to this question was to consider a function where f(2) is defined and f'(x) is not; for instance: f(x)= |x-2|. I believe that since f'(2) is undefined, f''(2) should also be undefined; please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's correct. The derivative is undefined at any point where the function is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your time and assistance. I cannot describe this scenario's context since this question was proposed without complementary information.

Comment: Note that you can discuss maxima and minima even if the derivative does not exist. For the example of $f(x)=|x-2|$, the function has a minimum at $x=2$ even though it has no derivative (or second derivative) there.

Comment: By definition, $f''(2)=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f'(x)-f'(2)}{x-2}$. So you need the value of $f'(2)$ to talk about $f''(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

How can $ f''(2)$ exist if $f'(2)$ does not exist?So,the condition is meaningless.